# display date with last month information

Tags: linux

I know the command many display current month and year .

```
#date +%b%Y

Jun2015
```

If I want to show the last month and year ( as current month is Jun2015, I would like display May2015 , if current is Jan2016 , then display Dec2015 ) , would advise what can I do ? thanks

Comment: Running `date -d 'this month 1 -1 day' +%F` give the last day of previous month (usefull if you want to know how many day previous mounth count.)

Answer (score 1):

```
date --date='-1 month' +'%b%Y'
```

example:

```
date --date='-7 month' +'%b%Y'
```

Gives: "Nov2014"

Answer (score 1):

you can specify a relative date you want to be printed:

```
$ date --date 'last month' +'%b%Y'
May2015
```